# Missing module error when setting up Mercurial on IIS

Tags: python, python-2.7, iis, mercurial, iis-8

I am following [these](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebInIisOnWindows) [instructions](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/mercurial-on-iis7/) to serve Mercurial repositories over IIS. I get the following error when running the `hgweb.cgi` script (recreated in a command prompt):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "hgweb.py", line 18, in
>   
>       application = hgweb(config)   File "mercurial\hgweb__init__.pyc", line 40, in hgweb
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 146, in **getattr**
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 91, in _load
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 42, in _hgextimport
>
> File "mercurial\hgweb\hgwebdir_mod.pyc", line 17, in
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 244, in
>   _demandimport
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 42, in _hgextimport
>
> File "mercurial\hgweb\common.pyc", line 23, in
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 146, in **getattr**
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 91, in _load
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 42, in _hgextimport
>
> File "mercurial\util.pyc", line 53, in 
>       '0beec7b5ea3f0fdbc95d0dd47f3c5bc275da8a33'   File "mercurial\policy.pyc", line 98, in importmod
>
> File "mercurial\policy.pyc", line 68, in _importfrom
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 160, in **doc**
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 91, in _load
>
> File "hgdemandimport\demandimportpy2.pyc", line 42, in _hgextimport
>
> File "mercurial\cext\base85.pyc", line 12, in
>
> File "mercurial\cext\base85.pyc", line 10, in __load
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I am using:

- Python 2.7.
- Mercurial 4.3.3.
- Mercurial Python modules from [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Download#Windows) (x64).
- Windows Server 2012 R2 x64.
- IIS 8.5.

The example "It works!" test.cgi displays OK so I know that the IIS handler mapping to Python is correct.

The online resources are a bit light and inconsistent, and I don't find the error message particularly helpful. Can anyone help me fix this issue? How do I find out which module is missing, and where to get it?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Do **not** copy the Mercurial library in to your application directory as it says to in [this guide](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/mercurial-on-iis7/). The information on there is outdated but is still linked to from the Mercurial wiki.